# Google Analytics Account ID through Rest API

Tags: c#, api, rest, google-analytics-api

I need to fetch Google analytics data according to my metrics.

Made from this tool http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/

```
string uriBuilder = string.Format(@"https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga
?ids=ga:{0}
&dimensions=ga:medium,ga:source,ga:campaign,ga:userType
&metrics=ga:newUsers,ga:users,ga:percentNewSessions
&filters=ga:medium=={1},ga:campaign=={2},ga:source=={3}
&start-date={4}
&end-date={5}
&access_token={6}"
, analyticsProfileId
, string_utnMedium
, string_utnCampaign
, string_utnSource
, startdate.ToString("yyyy-dd-mm")
, enddate.ToString("yyyy-dd-mm")
, accessToken);
```

> **Problem:** How to get "analyticsProfileId" ?

I got accessToken from below scope code

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
```

From their documentation i did't get the required "analyticsProfileId", below given is the code that i used

```
string.Format(@"https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts?access_token={0}", accessToken);
```

Any idea how to get the "analyticsProfileId" ? all thoughts are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is in the URL

Below URL will work

```
https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts/~all/webproperties/~all/profiles?access_token={0}
```

Check [this document for reference](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/analytics/v3/analytics.management.profiles.list)